# How to convert JSON data inside a pandas column into new columns....column name="level_options"

Tags: python, json, pandas, nested, ordereddictionary

i have used this code where i supposed to get 6[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QTPqF.png) lists but got empty lists for all

```
Option1=[] 
Option2=[] 
Option3=[] 
Option4=[] 
Option5=[]
Correct_option=[]
 try:
>     for index, row in df.iterrows():
>         l=row["level_options"]
>         print(l) except:
>     print(index,row)
>     l = json.loads(l) 
>     print(l)
>     for i in l:
>         i = json.loads(i) 
>         print(i)
>         if i['options'] == '1':
>             Option1.append(i['value'])
>         elif i['options'] == '2':
>             Option2.append(i['value'])
>         elif i['options'] == '3':
>             Option3.append(i['value'])
>         elif i['options'] == '4':
>             Option4.append(i['value'])
>         elif i['options'] == '5':
>             Option5.append(i['value'])
>         elif i['options'] == 'correct_options':
>             Correct_option.append(i['value'])
```

here is 2 rows of df["level_options"]

> {"marking": "normal", "options": {"1": "Carbon dioxide", "2":
> "Oxygen", "3": "Urine", "4": "Sweat"}, "max_score": 1,
> "random_options": "false", "correct_options": ["2"]} {"marking":
> "normal", "options": {"1": "Yes", "2": "No"}, "max_score": 1,
> "random_options": "false", "correct_options": ["1"]}

output I am expecting

```
options.1   options.2     options.3 options.4  options.5    correct_options    
Carbon dioxide  Oxygen      Urine      Sweat       NaN               [2]    
Yes              No           NaN        NaN        NaN               [1]
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: below i gave 2 rows of level_option column , how to make them in the required format that i shared in the image(options1,option2 like that multiple columns)
{"marking": "normal", "options": {"1": "Carbon dioxide", "2": "Oxygen", "3": "Urine", "4": "Sweat"}, "max_score": 1, "random_options": false, "correct_options": ["2"]}
{"marking": "normal", "options": {"1": "Yes", "2": "No"}, "max_score": 1, "random_options": false, "correct_options": ["1"]}

Comment: in the same way this column has to convert ............2 rows of extra_info column
["{\"name\": \"readme\", \"value\": \"\"}", "{\"name\": \"skill\", \"value\": \"Integration\"}", "{\"name\": \"sub_skill\", \"value\": \"Integration RH1\"}"]
["{\"name\": \"readme\", \"value\": \"\"}", "{\"name\": \"skill\", \"value\": \"Integration\"}", "{\"name\": \"sub_skill\", \"value\": \"Integration RH1\"}"]

Comment: how to clean this............................ into columns as option 1, option 2, so on
 {"marking": "normal",
 "options": {
  "1": "Carbon dioxide",
  "2": "Oxygen",
  "3": "Urine",
  "4": "Sweat"
 },
 "max_score": 1,
 "random_options": false,
 "correct_options": ["2"]
} {
 "marking": "normal",
 "options": {
  "1": "Yes",
  "2": "No"
 },
 "max_score": 1,
 "random_options": false,
 "correct_options": ["1"]
}

Answer (score 0):

Try this snippet:

```
import json    
li=[]
    for ind in df1.index:
        temp=json.load(df1["level_options"][ind])
        temp.update(json.load(df1["extra_info"][ind]))
        li.append(pd.json_normalize(temp))
    li
```

Here, after the iteration of the loop the List  `li`  will have the required data.

Comment: Thanks but it shows this error-------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [66], in <cell line: 2>()
      2 for ind in df1.index:
      3     temp=df1["level_options"][ind]
----> 4     temp.update(df1["extra_info"][ind])
      5     li.append(pd.json_normalize(temp))
      6 li

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'update'

Comment: df shape is (42380, 12) and  these columns=============Index(['level_id', 'description', 'level_type', 'difficulty', 'solution',
       'modifier', 'last_modified', 'time_limit', 'tags', 'level_options',
       'extra_info', 'hint'],
      dtype='object')//////////////////////i want to clean these two column in the required format that i shared in the image

Comment: have edited the answer a bit

Comment: again throws error================AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
----->4     temp=json.load(df["level_options"][ind])
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'

Comment: Can you specify what is the datatype of the data stored in df["level_options"][ind]

Comment: type of df['level_options'] = pandas.core.series.Series

Comment: here i elaborate my que.................https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73345471/jsonnested-dictionary-data-inside-a-pandas-column-into-new-columns-column